# Handle XML-text-content without enclosing markup tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform xml-data with a xsl-transformation. I have some nodes which contain text and child-elements.

I'm not able to wrap the text between the child elements into separat markup-tags

```xml
…
<content>
    some text 1
    <child>child 1</child>
    some text 2
    <child>child 2</child>
    some text 3
    <child>child 3</child>
    some text 4
</content>
…
```

The desired output would be:

```xml
…
<markup>some text 1</markup>
<child>child 1</child>
<markup>some text 2</markup>
<child>child 2</child>
<markup>some text 3</markup>
<child>child 3</child>
<markup>some text 4</markup>
…
```

I tried the following:

```xml
<xsl:template match="content">
    <xsl:for-each select="./text()">
        <markup>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </markup>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child">
    …
</xsl:template>
```

The result ist now some duplicate content:

```xml
<markup>some text 1</markup>
<markup>some text 2</markup>
<markup>some text 3</markup>
<markup>some text 4</markup>
some text 1<child>child 1</child>some text 2<child>child 2</child>some text 3<child>child 3</child>some text 4
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Please show your code and and edit the question to add the appropriate language  tag.

Comment: @GabrielDevillers i edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content/text()">
    <markup>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </markup>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried to combine your answer with my code. I'm almost there – but now get some duplicate content. I added to results to my question above.

Comment: It cannot work the way you're trying. When you do `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, you are applying templates to text nodes too. If you exclude them, you will get all the text nodes first, then all the `child` elements.